# TextView hyphenation below API 23

Tags: android, textview, hyphenation, soft-hyphen

In API 23 TextView hyphenates text correctly:
`longwooord\u00AD1231232131` is correctly split from the `\u00AD` char resulting in `longwooord-` and `1231232131` on the next line.
However for API 21 `\u00AD` is just ignored and word is split where it reaches text area's right border. Is there any way to replicate API 23 hyphenation behaviour in API 21?